# electron-packager: Unable to create OSX package "The strict-ssl parameter is deprecated, use download.strictSSL..."

Tags: npm, electron

I am trying to create Electron package for OSX however I am ending up having the following error.

```
The strict-ssl parameter is deprecated, use download.strictSSL instead
Cannot create symlinks; skipping darwin platform
```

Please help. Many Thanks.

I am running the following command

```
electron-packager . --out=dist/osx --platform=darwin --arch=x64
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. Still not really fixed with 7.0.1.
https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/issues/349